# 4 buttons do not want to arrange into a square

Tags: html

I have 4 buttons (example):

```
<button>
<button> <br>
<button>
<button>
```

They should be 2 rows of buttons with 2 buttons each, arranged in a perfect square of buttons (the buttons are 130px x 130px) 
Instead, I need to use 8 `<br>`'s to create 2 rows of buttons, and there is a large gap which ruins the perfect square. 
If I use only 7 `<br>`'s, I get 2 semi-rows of buttons, where the rows are just short of not touching corners
How could I fix this?

Comment: Use 2 wrapper div, add 2 buttons in a div

Comment: did that, didn't work and has the exact same effect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way would be to wrap your buttons in a `div`, set `max-width` and use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Mastering_Wrapping_of_Flex_Items). That is because you also explicitly set the width and height of each button which then makes sense to use explicit `width` on a parent `div` as well.

Have a look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/9m5b0s8x/).

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, the html was acting really weird and I couldn't think how to fix it (the 4th button would be slightly downward from the rest of the buttons for some reason?)

Comment: It is all good, as long as we could make it work. Is there still an issue despite the example that I have given, that you might still need help with? (make sure there are no additional `margins`, if there are then you might need to adjust `max-width` to account for that.

Comment: No, it all works fine. Thank you! I need to read up on more CSS and find out what a flexbox is...

Comment: Great to hear. Indeed it is a good idea to learn more about `flexbox`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

*I am not sure what did you try (as you mentioned in comments).*

As the `div` is block displayed element it will take full width of container. So remaining content will be pushed on to next line.

```html
<div>
   <button>Button 1</button>
   <button>Button 2</button>
</div>
<button>Button 3</button>
<button>Button 4</button>
```